# Word for a song with defamatory content, written and spread to mock the one or what the song is about?

Tags: word-request

In Norwegian we got the word "nidvise" ("nid"-song) for a song with "defamatory content, written and spread to mock the one or what the song is about".  Is there a word for such a song in English?  I suppose it's sort of satire, but that doesn't quite cover it...

Examples: [If Jesse Don't Like It](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtb2Wn8tEmM), about former Senator Jesse Helms.

Comment: Can you clarify "defamatory" here? In the US (and I think most areas with English as their primary language), something that's just insulting isn't the same as defamation...defamation has to involve an actual, believable falsehood (either a known lie or a reckless disregard for truth). And there are some pretty big loopholes for "satire" and "mere vulgar abuse". So specifically the song you linked to doesn't seem to be defamatory.

Comment: Why doesn't 'satire' work?

Comment: How do you talk about the songs of Tom Lehrer in Norwegian?  Wikipedia uses both "parody" and "political satire" to describe his work.

Answer (score 11):

These are quite common in the hip-hop scene and they call them 'diss tracks':

> A diss track or diss song (diss – abbreviated from *disrespect*) is a song whose primary purpose is to verbally attack someone else, usually another artist. Diss tracks are often the result of an existing, escalating feud between the two people; for example, the artists involved may be former members of a group, or artists on rival labels.

(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diss_(music)))

Comment: I think diss tracks are more personal feud than political satire.

Comment: True. It doesn't really fit the example, but it does fit "defamatory content, written and spread to mock the one or what the song is about".

Answer (score 6):

A [burlesque](https://www.lexico.com/definition/burlesque) is a parody: an absurd or comically exaggerated imitation of something.
A [philippic](https://www.lexico.com/definition/philippic) is a bitter attack or denunciation, especially a verbal one. Such songs are always topical, attacking or denouncing someone in power.

A [Juvenalian](https://www.lexico.com/definition/juvenalian_satire) is characterized by bitter, scathing humour and a morally indignant tone.

A [Horatian](https://www.lexico.com/definition/horatian_satire) is a gentle, mocking satire aimed at making people laugh.

A [Jeremiad](https://www.lexico.com/definition/jeremiad) is long, mournful complaint or lamentation; a list of woes. No target is necessary.

A [broadside](https://www.lexico.com/definition/broadside) is a fierce verbal attack. (Not to be confused with a [broadside ballad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadside_ballad))

Comment: It is worth noting that none of these would make any sense to a layperson. Although technically correct they would only be understandable to a minuscule number of people and so should be avoided in casual conversation

Comment: Of these, I only knew "burlesque" without reading the explanation.

Comment: @AlexReinking  I think most people think that they know what "Burlesque" means, but def not THIS meaning!  "Broadside" however is a fairly general term for a verbal attack, whether in print or as part of (say) a parliamentary speech.

Answer (score 4):

You might be referring to a song **parody**.

There are different ideas about what song parodies are - most people consider song parodies to be recordings which use the music from a known song with new lyrics that either mock the original lyrics or some other subject entirely. However, 'parody' is sometimes also used to describe *satirical* songs, which may parody, or mock a subject in a completely original musical work. A musical parody can also imitate a *style* of music or that of an artist rather than directly imitate a specific song.

One of the most famous musical parody acts is ["Weird Al" Yankovic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Weird_Al%22_Yankovic), who writes all of the above kinds of song parody.

Your example of Loudon Wainright III is a little harder to define - I wouldn't consider him a parody artist, even though the song you gave as an example is humorous.  It could be singly called a 'comedy song' or a 'satirical song', but this kind of song isn't the artist's only kind of output. The genres of folk and country music, which often have 'story-telling' lyrics, often use humour as a way of dealing with an otherwise serious subject but are not comedy. Some comedy musicians have chosen the country or folk genre as the vehicle for their humour, but this is very different from a credible country or folk artist using a little humour in their songs.

Comment: I suppose it would work if I was mocking a singer/artist and exaggerated their song-style and/or typical lyrics &c...  Not sure it would fit if I was singing mockingly about a politician or similar though.

Comment: @BaardKopperud The endless YouTube videos which turn known pop songs into songs about Trump and the like are usually termed 'parodies', rightly or wrongly. So yes, a song mocking a political figure may be a parody. The parody songs of 'Weird' Al often feature lyrics about a completely different subject to the song they draw from, so they are more directly mocking the lyrical subject matter than the original music artist.

Comment: @Astralbee  I agree that political satire shouldn't really be labelled as 'parodies', but is that now turning into common usage?

Comment: @MikeBrockington Going off YouTube content, and my 12-year old's definition of what a 'parody' is - yes, that is common usage.

Comment: to be honest, I wouldn't at all assume parody fits in the sense of this question - it is just something explicitly derivative and typically funny. But I'm older so maybe things are changing as other folks claim.

Comment: @MikeM I don't think I've 'assumed' anything, I've given quite some detail as to what might be covered by the term. The problem with taking the question at face value is the example might well be considered a parody by modern use of the word, but not in the traditional sense; and the artist may not be considered a parody artist, but that doesn't mean they aren't capable of writing a parody. The OP can use some discernment as to what fits their bill, they've had several answers now.

Comment: Work that mocks or defames a person _can_ be parody, but that is utterly unrelated to the work's mocking or defamatory qualities. From the other side: parody does not imply mocking or defamatory qualities.

Answer (score 2):

An appropriate name might be **satirical song**. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Satirical_songs) includes a very incomplete list of satirical songs. They all mock some topic and several mock particular people. For example, Monty Python's [Contractual Obligation Album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python%27s_Contractual_Obligation_Album) includes satirical songs about Henry Kissinger and John Denver.

Answer (score 1):

[**Doggerel**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doggerel) is verse, and can be song.  It is deliberately written poorly, and thus parodies verse-writing, but often the subject of the verse is also targeted, such that the subject is mocked through its connection to the deliberately poor writing.

If a song is overtly political, and mocks a political figure or party for the benefit of an opposing group, it can be considered musical **[Propaganda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_and_political_warfare)**.  For example, the British 1914 song "Hoch, Hoch the Kaiser" [mocks the leader of Germany](https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00682095/document), for the purpose of unifying 'home front' sentiment.